# WebSocket/HTTP, which Protocol used by C++ SOCKET type by default and how it works herer?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I am learning C++ to understand the basics and internals of networking, how system works. For that I was following a tutorial for building chat application. Here is the code:

**ChatServer**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

/*
    Initialize winsock Library
    Create Socket
    Get IP and Port
    Bind IP/Porrt with Socket
    Listen on the socket
    Accept 
    Rec and Send
    Close the Socket
    Clean up the Lib
*/

bool Initialization() {
    WSADATA data;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data) == 0;
}

void InteractionWithClient(SOCKET clientSocket, vector<SOCKET>& clients) {
    char buffer[4096];
    while (true) {
        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (bytesReceived <= 0) {
            cout << "Client Dosconnected\n";
            break;
        }
        string message(buffer, bytesReceived);
        cout << "Message from Client: " << message << endl;

        for (auto client : clients) {
            if(client != clientSocket) 
                send(client, message.c_str(), message.length(), 0);
        }
    }
    auto it = find(clients.begin(), clients.end(), clientSocket);
    if (it != clients.end())
        clients.erase(it);
    closesocket(clientSocket);
}

int main() {
    const int PORT = 12345;
    if (!Initialization()) {
        cout << "WinSock Initialization Failed " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Chat Server" << endl;

    SOCKET listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Socket Creation Failed " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);


    if (InetPton(AF_INET, _T("0.0.0.0"), &serverAddr.sin_addr) != 1) {
        cout << "Setting Address structure Failed" << endl;
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(listenSocket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&serverAddr), sizeof serverAddr) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Socket Binding to Address Failed" << endl;
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (listen(listenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Server Listening Failed" << endl;
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Server Started on Port " << PORT << endl;

    vector<SOCKET> clients;
    while (true) {
        SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listenSocket, nullptr, nullptr);
        if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            cout << "Invalid Client Socket" << endl;
        }

        clients.push_back(clientSocket);
        thread t(InteractionWithClient, clientSocket, std::ref(clients));
        t.detach();
    }
    
    closesocket(listenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

**Client**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

/*
    Initialize winsock Library
    Create Socket
    Get IP and Port
    Bind IP/Porrt with Socket
    Listen on the socket
    Accept
    Rec and Send
    Close the Socket
    Clean up the Lib
*/

bool Initialization() {
    WSADATA data;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data) == 0;
}

void SendMessageToServer(SOCKET s) {
    cout << "SendMessageToServer:: socket " << s << endl;
    cout << "Enter You Chat name:\t";
    string name;
    getline(cin, name);
    string message;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Message:: \t";
        getline(cin, message);

        if (message == "quit") {
            cout << "Stopping the application\n";
            break;
        }

        message = name + " :: " + message;
        int bytesSent = send(s, message.c_str(), message.length(), 0);
        if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "Error Sending Message\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
}

void ReceiveMessage(SOCKET s) {
    cout << "ReceiveMessage:: socket " << s << endl;
    char buffer[4096];
    int recvLength;
    string msg;
    while (true) {
        recvLength = recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (recvLength <= 0) {
            cout << "Disconned from the Server\n";
            break;
        }
        msg = string(buffer, recvLength);
        cout << msg << endl;
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
}

int main() {
    const int PORT = 12345;
    if (!Initialization()) {
        cout << "WinSock Initialization Failed " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Chat Server" << endl;

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Socket Creation Failed " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    InetPton(AF_INET, _T("127.0.0.1"), &serverAddr.sin_addr);

    if (connect(s, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&serverAddr), sizeof serverAddr) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Socket Binding to Server Address Failed" << endl;
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    cout << "Successfully connected to server\n";
    thread senderThread(SendMessageToServer, s);
    thread receiverThread(ReceiveMessage, s);

    senderThread.join();
    receiverThread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

While doing, I got couple of doubts.

1. What protocol does SOCKET in C++ use? Is it WebSocket,HTTP or what? Seeing the implementation, it appears that it's a websocket?
2. In Client Code, Why do we need to call closeSocket(s) in each of the thread functions separately ie SendMessageToServer and ReceiveMessage? Can it be called just once in the main function since the same Socket instance is used by both the threads and closing it in any of the thread should ideally reflect to both of them? Pls correct me if this assumption is wrong.

Also, pls provide some resource regarding this.

Comment: `SOCK_STREAM` is TCP/IP; an unstructured stream of octets.

Comment: @molbdnilo "*`SOCK_STREAM` is TCP/IP*" - not exactly. TCP is a stream, but a stream is not necessarily TCP.  `IPPROTO_TCP` is the *default* for `SOCK_STREAM` when the `protocol` parameter is 0, but there are other protocols that also use `SOCK_STREAM`, such as `IPPROTO_SCTP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What protocol does SOCKET in C++ use?

It does not use any specific well known protocol, i.e. no HTTP, no WebSocket etc

> ... it appears that it's a websocket?

It's not. Websockets start with a HTTP handshake and then has some specific framing for message - this protocol here has none of this.

In addition, it looks like the author of the code suffers from common mistakes when using TCP sockets: assuming that `send` sends everything (not checked if only part is sent) and wrongly assuming that there is a 1:1 relationship between `send` and `recv`.

> In Client Code, Why do we need to call closeSocket(s) in each of the thread functions separately ie SendMessageToServer and ReceiveMessage?  Can it be called just once in the main function since the same Socket instance is used by both the threads and closing it in any of the thread should ideally reflect to both of them?

This finding is correct. The code shown here is also broken in this regard. Therefore I recommend to not follow this specific tutorial anymore if you want to learn how to properly implement socket communication.

Comment: "assuming that send sends everything (not checked if only part is sent) and wrongly assuming that there is a 1:1 relationship between send and recv." - The implementation will be something like https://cplusplus.com/forum/general/266899/#msg1148369

Also, some identifier should be sent to the backend through which it understands that the complete message isn't sent yet, so don't process the segment yet (i.e. store in DB or send to other user) and also some message id of which the segment if part of and also some order key to keep track of the ordering of segments.

Comment: If all the metadata in the comment mentioned is required, then we can't directly send the plain msg to the backend, a wrapper or some header is required to manage all this. Does for these low level handling, HTTP is created so that it can handle segmentation, ordering, completion, etc, if I am understanding it right.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh: Your original question is answered, please don't follow up with other questions inside comments. But in very short:  HTTP has a very specific use case. request a resource from the client and returns the resource from the server. It handles all the stuff you mention  but also much more, so it might be overly complex if you just want message framing. A common way is just to add a fixed-size header to each message which contains the size of the message.

Answer (score 2):

> What protocol does SOCKET in C++ use?

Sockets created with AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM are a handle reference to an underlying TCP/IP connection. Specifically TCP (SOCK_STREAM) on top of IPv4 (AF_INET).

More generically, sockets are the objects in code that a variety of network protocols can use.

> In Client Code, Why do we need to call closeSocket(s) in each of the thread functions separately ie SendMessageToServer and ReceiveMessage? Can it be called just once in the main function since the same Socket instance is used by both the threads and closing it in any of the thread should ideally reflect to both of them? Pls correct me if this assumption is wrong.

A socket (handle) should only be closed exactly once. Closing a socket handle twice can actually lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: "A socket (handle) should only be closed exactly once. Closing a socket handle twice can actually lead to unexpected behavior." - I think the right way would be to keep it in sendMessage function. As soon as it got exited, "recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) < 0" and we can also exit the receiveMessage function since the socket is closed. Is this a right assumption?

Comment: @selbie "*Sockets created with `AF_INET` and `SOCK_STREAM` are a handle reference to an underlying TCP/IP connection*" - only if the socket was created with the `protocol` parameter set to `0` or `IPPROTO_TCP`. There are other protocols that also use `SOCK_STREAM`, such as `IPPROTO_SCTP`.